# Create a folder in a virtual folder with c#

Tags: c#, directory, virtual, create-directory

I created a virtual folder in IIS. 
In my website, I want to create folders IN that virtual folder.
I tried multiple options, none worked. 
This was one of them:

```
Directory.CreateDirectory(~/[virtual folder]/[map that doesn't exist]);
```

I guess it's taking the project folder and not referencing to the real folder.
Does anyone has an idea how to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: to create the directory surely you must give a full path? Directory.CreateDirectory(~/ is trying to use a path that is relative to the root of the website '~/' and then you want to use a virtual directory ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Physical path is the answer thanks to Paul Zahra.